# Using NSIS for designing a Simple UI to control Application

Tags: installation, nsis, win32gui

I need to design a simple UI for Windows platform with a few buttons like Start server, Stop server, Launch client, Check for updates etc.
This UI will front end batch scripts so that users don't have to look for specific batch scripts to run.

I am already using NSIS for installation of the software and find it pretty cool and easy to use. I am considering using NSIS to design this simple UI so I do not have to write a lot of Win SDK code.

Will it be a bad idea to create this front end using NSIS just because NSIS is primarily used for creating installers?

Is there something as easy as designing the simple window with buttons?

I also have one concern. While an NSIS installer is running can it block another unrelated installer from running. I don't want my UI to block other installations from happening while it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating applications with NSIS/[nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) is OK for simple little things, I have done it myself several times. It should not block other installers but it does try to prevent reboots...

You could also take a look at [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) or create a [HTA application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).